# How to call a clearInterval() method from one function to stop a setInterval() method in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, intervals

so I'm basically creating a slideshow using some basic cross fading below is the script I am currently using

**Script:**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var slide = function(){
                                var active = $('.active');
                                var next = (active.next().length > 0) ? active.next() : $('#slide:first');
                                next.css('z-index',2);
                                active.fadeOut(1000,function(){// fade out the active image
                                                                active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');
                                                                next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');
                                });
                              }
        setInterval(slide,2000)
  });
```

As you can see the above script cross fades a list of images every 2s . Now what I want to do is to stop the slideshow (ie. use `clearInterval(Interval id)` ) when the user clicks on either the `previous image` button or on the `next image` button but it dosent seem to work.i have tried examples from w3schools.com etc but to no avail

---

**Update**

**The Complete Script** in case of any doubts

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var slide = function(){
                                var active = $('.active');
                                var next = (active.next().length > 0) ? active.next() : $('#slide:first');
                                next.css('z-index',2);
                                active.fadeOut(1000,function(){// fade out the active image
                                                                active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');
                                                                next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');
                                });
                              }
        setInterval(slide,2000)
  });

  //------------on click of next or prev-------
  //next
  $(".next").click(function(){
          window.clearInterval(slide_timer);//stop the auto slide

          var active = $('.active');
          var next = (active.next().length > 0) ? active.next() : $('#slide:first');
          next.css('z-index',2);
          active.fadeOut(1000,function(){// fade out the active image
                                          active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');
                                          next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');
          });
  });
  //prev will be the same as next as soon as the stopping slide show problem is solved
```

Comment: `setInterval()` returns a value. Save that value in a variable, and that's what you pass to `clearInterval()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example to implement yours..

```js
var interval;
$('#stop').click(function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
});

var slide = function(){
    alert("testing setInterval");
}

interval = setInterval(slide,2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="stop">stop interval</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

pull your interval reference out to a higher level of scope.

```
var slideInterval;

function triggerTimer(){
    slideInterval= setInterval(slide,2000);
}

function cancelTimer(){
    clearInterval(slideInterval);
}
```